# Liferay, Mediawiki import (code) changes

Tags: liferay, mediawiki

I'm actually implementing to export a bunch of 'mediaWiki' pages and import them into the Liferay Wiki.

So, as per the existing process, I exported all the required necessary pages into an '*.xml' file and did an import from the Control Panel.

The problem:

When I check the parsed/rendered pages, I see sections of the page isn't rendered appropriately. Upon further digging, I noticed that the sections that weren't rendered are the places which had the `'<table>'` as `'{|'` (in wiki) and upon looking further, I noticed that in the page 'html\portlet\wiki\help\mediawiki.jsp' there isn't a specific rule that describes `'{|'` as being a `'<table>'` tag.

So, my Question is, if there is a place/source-file to which I can edit and/or add the necessary rules to. If not, what would be the ideal solution for this?

Note: You can see the actual 'wikipedia' formatting rules for a table in this page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Table#Using_the_toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to post-process the XML file.  That way you can transform the table markup however you want.  A better resource for the table markup is [on mediawiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTables)